# Which server is the best for a client/server iphone app?

Tags: iphone, client, store

I wanna build a client server iphone app and for this i need to store data on a server and download the data to iphone app when the app is runing.

The data from the server is not for everyone. Each user has to see only the data which is related to that user. (like social networking sites works, each user has a different home page). For this app, i will need to store a lot of users ( i hope :)) ), each user has some friends and communicate with them, and that data should be stored on the server.

So, for something like this which is the best server? Google AppEngine or Amazon S3 or Amazon EC2 or another one?

I don't wanna waste time to build my own server, configure it, etc...

Comment: How long is a piece of string? What do you have skillset in? It's no use recommending AppEngine if you can't code python or Java, same with heroku or engineyard if you can't code ruby. To be honest, it sounds like you need to brush up on the basics before you launch into a "client server iphone app"

Comment: a string is 200-300 characters maximum. I have an app which is now "in review" and in that app I communicate with a server for push notifications. For that i used JSON, and the server was configured for that. From what you say I prefer Java or Python but i don't have to much experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give Python + GAE a look, too.

Comment: till now this is in pole position :). Because i found an example and it's not hard to understand.                                      Here is the example: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-iphone/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Ruby on Rails and running it on [Heroku](http://heroku.com/)

Comment: Did you use this on something? Do you know someone who uses? Or what is the reason you suggest this. Thanks